# What can be done when the magnetic compass breaks during a cross country flight?

Tags: aircraft-maintenance, magnetic-compass

On United state a VFR cross country flight, after arriving you discover that the magnetic compass has leaked all of the fluid and is inoperative.

The weather at airport shows a fast moving cold front has just passed the night before. The winds aloft at 3000 feet and up were forecast to be very strong an the surface winds were forecast to be calm. The briefer also said that the pressure was falling rapidly. The ATIS/AWOS stated the winds as 270 at 15 kt. When you arrived at the airport, the wind sock showed the wind from the east at the arrival end of the runway you were planning to use.

What can you do?

Comment: Welcome to Aviation.SE! Are you asking if it is legal to takeoff and continue your cross country flights? If so, please add a country/regulation tag (e.g. [faa-regulations]) since legality might differ.

Comment: I vote to close as this question is disjointed and lacks clarity.

Comment: The title question is clear enough, but the scenario based narrative in the body is a bit distracting.  (the windsock is as irrelevant to the question as the milkshake is to the answer!)  It boils down to required equipment for VFR/IFR flight, and nothing more.  Which wouldn't be a bad question in itself, but easily searchable info...

Comment: Just as a practical matter, how often do you consult the magnetic compass when flying VFR?  I'm almost always flying by reference to terrain.

Comment: Since the question is "What can you do?", not "What can you do to remain in compliance with regulations", the best answer would be "you can just go fly".  Much of the US is covered by an east-west north-south road grid system anyway.  Just don't forget to look out the windows now and then.  If that seems like too much of a handful, perhaps you might want to bring along a hand-held gps unit.  Or your smart phone- just use google maps.

Comment: @MichaelHall: It's a great teaching technique. Now if one finds a broken compass, they'll think of milkshake, and remember that it's required! ;)

Answer (score 10):

If you're in the United States and your airplane has a standard airworthiness certificate, you can go to the airport restaurant and order a milkshake while you wait for your magnetic compass to be fixed, since it's required equipment under [14 CFR 91.205](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/91.205):

> (b) Visual-flight rules (day). For VFR flight during the day, the following instruments and equipment are required: [...]
>
> 3. Magnetic direction indicator.

Comment: You may want to check the ATIS before deciding on a milkshake or hot chocolate.

Comment: ...It's a trap!

Comment: Is the pilot vaccinated 